# Simple C string initialization concept clarification needed

Tags: c, string, initialization

If I have a C string initialization like this:

```
char a[5]={'a','b','c'};
```

Is this valid?
What's the value of a[3] and a[4]?
Is the null character automatically attached to the end of a?

Thanks!

Comment: The last two elements should be indeterminate or uninitialized IMO.

Comment: _If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration._ 6.7.8 Initialization 21

Answer (score 5):

They would be initialized to a value of 0. Null is automatically added when you leave some elements uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `C` std you are following:

- If you follow `C90` STRICTLY then it forbids you to do it, Thanks BLUEPIXY for the enlightenment
- Then, there are certain extensions to these standards which enable you to compile this code without any error, in which case, this is fine.

So, in case of the later, `C` language takes care by initializing rest to zero .

```
char a[5] = {}
```

initializes all indexes to zero.

Comment: I think when somebody down votes, he should convey the reason for doing so.

Comment: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces.

Comment: No, ISO C99 allows it:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Also, the same has been answered here at SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: you try `gcc prog.c -std=c99 -pedantic`

Comment: You seem to be creating a program that takes a long time really.

Comment: Oh..You shared the link to the ideone code.. remember? I trust you :)

Comment: How is that so?? Please look at the top ans, says the exact same thing ! It has 5 votes, are you challenging those 5 voters ?

Answer (score 0):

If called within a function a[3] and a[4] will be uninitiallised. That is to say, they will be whatever happens to be sitting in memory at the time.

If declared outside a function, a[3] and a[4] will be set to 0.

Comment: This is not true. Missing indexes in initializer are treated as zero.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the implementation I believe that the last elements of an array will be either completely random or just equivalents of 0's or even something else, but besides of that array will get initialized just fine.